# No bibliography output of Sweave/LaTeX document

Tags: compilation, latex, rstudio, sweave, bibtex

**Code**

```
\usepackage{babelbib}

...

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{LV}
```

I'm getting no output (bibliography). Installing the bibtex dependencies again for tex-live with no results. How to proceed?

The document is written in, and compiled from, RStudio using the button "Compile PDF".

I asked this question also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306235/no-bibliography-output?noredirect=1) but there they do not know anythin about R Studio

Answer (score 0):

Using \cite{...} works, but for each article which is not cited \cite{Article_i} has to be inserted in the document to create the bibliography (the bbl file). After it all unnecessary citations (\cite{Article_i}) have to be deleted and a new compilation the bibliography is inserted to the document.

Do you have any idea how to use \nocite{*} not to go the way using \cite?